# How are my const and non-const Linked List Iterators different?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I have four classes, two of them iterators:

```
LinkedList<T> -- holds the pointer to dummy node
LinkedListNode<T> -- Node with next and previous pointers and data T
LinkedListIterator<T> -- holds a pointer to LinkedListNode
LinkedListConstIterator<T> -- holds a pointer to LinkedListNode
```

They both only need to implement forward iterator functionality.

How would the functions in my const iterator be different in this case? Does it just mean that when I return a pointer or anything to the user, I should make it const?

Comment: Ideally your `LinkedListConstIterator` would hold its pointers as something like `const LinkedListNode<T>*`, so that the decision as to the return type is even more obvious: the "const" variant walks over a const view of the underlying nodes and values—unless you want to allow editing the structure of the list (say, removing an element pointed to by a const iterator), in which case you need to walk over a non-const view of the nodes, perhaps as `LinkedListNode<const T>*`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how `const_iterators` work for any STL container (example: [std::list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/)). If you're looking for your iterator classes to work similarly then yes, you should be returning a reference to a const value, i.e. `const T&`